# how can I run hiero in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I have created a libgdx project using the installer from http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html and the Gradle extension for Android Studio.

Example for IntelliJ IDEA: Go to the Hiero class, right click and select Run Hiero.main(). On the Run >configurations popup that will appear, select the Desktop module, and click Run.

How do you do this under Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the procedure. I leave the answer for those fellow beginners who may come across this problem like me:

> go to structure tab beneath the project tab and the rest is the same as the above example for IntelliJ IDEA